# Trying to do multiple tabs using \t

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to print a certain string each time on a new line and each line adding a new tab.

For example:

```
String
      String
           String
```

The code I used:

```
print(string + "\n\t" + string "\n\t" + string)
```

Which gives the output:

```
String
      String
      String
```

Can someone explain me why is it happening, and what are the ways to work around it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect your first result. You start a new line, and then have a single tab. If you want two tabs, you need to put two tabs.

Comment: \n jumps to a new line, but does o to the beginning of the line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `for` loop and add a tab in each cycle:

```
number = 3
string = "String"
for i in range(number):
    print('\t' * i + string + '\n', end="")
```

Output:

```
String
    String
        String
```

You can use it for any positive value of variable `number`. You can also create a function that does the above:

```
def printTabbed(number,string):
    for i in range(number):
        print('\t' * i + string + '\n', end="")
```

And then call it:

```
printTabbed(3,"String")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
print(string + "\n\t" + string "\n\t\t" + string)
```

In your code, the third line only contains one `tab` indent (indents don't "carry over" to the next lines, so you have to indent every line from the start).

Comment: Thanks for answer! So if I had to do something like printing a complex indented list I would have to use some kind a variable that would track the number of indentations I'm using?

Comment: @Daniel Exactly. For every line you need to determine its indentation, and print exactly as many `tabs`

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to do this multiple times it is best to use a loop such as this:

```
n = 10 // amount of times you want to print
for x in range(n):
    tabs = "\t"*x
    print(tabs+"String"+"\n")
```